# building a multi project node microservice

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, microservices, package.json

I am currently setting up a microservice project and I am running into some issues with building and running it.

So in essence I have a UI, a graphQL gateway, a couple of "leaf nodes", and some utility packages that keep our logging libraries etc.

All of these apps/services builds fine if I open a terminal for each and every one of them, which is less than ideal.

I thought it would make sense if I create a docker image for every service, but the issue is that it would need to follow symlinks.

The reason for it needing to follow symlinks is because that is how npm installs local packages. And I don't want to/cannot publish the packages anywhere.

So is there any common way of handling multiple servers in multiple node packages with dependencies to one another like this?

Comment: If I understand you well, what you're looking for is a container to deploy and run your applications.
Try checking about docker and docker-compose

Comment: sort of, but I am getting issues building the docker images as well, as they need to be able to follow symlinks... ex, the app server has this `"logging": "file:../logging"` which will result in a symlink in `/app/node_modules` to `/logging`, and docker does not seem to follow that symlink, causing it to fail

Comment: You should Google and read up on Monorepo(s). Yarn workspaces may accomplish what you need under node.